# DevExpress GridControl line numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

How to make column with row number? Solutions that works with default WPF dataGrid don't work with DevExpress...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a  unboundcolumn to your gridview, you can do this from the designer or from code.

```
var col = gridView1.Columns.Add();
col.FieldName = "counter";
col.Visible = true;
col.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Integer;
gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData;

void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsGetData)
        e.Value = e.ListSourceRowIndex+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the column caption to "#"
then add this event to the gridView1

```
    private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Caption == "#")
        {
            e.DisplayText = (e.RowHandle + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```